# Removing an existing field from an index in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am a newbie in Elastic search. I have an unwanted field in my index say index name "test_index". This contains almost 155154 documents. I want to remove an unwanted field "B" from my index. This is how my index pattern look like in json format

{A :  {B : {C: } }

I believe removing B will automatically remove C from my index as well.  In order to do that, I used the following query but it didn't seem to work.

```
POST test_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed {
      "script" : "ctx._source.A.remove('B')", 
       "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "A.B" }
      }
}
```

Please let me know where I am doing the mistake.

Thank you

Comment: Does your mapping have them as nested field? Your query has one typo if you are using kibana, but other than that its correct. Remove `:` after `conflicts=proceed`. If you are using some other way to run this - then check your mapping and make sure query runs if not whats the error/response?

Comment: Please add your mapping details and if any error messages.

Comment: @PolynomialProton Thank you for your response. I removed the ":" from my question actually it was a typo. Yes I am running it in kibana. I can see that for one of my index the query worked an removed the field. But it was not immediate, and I could not able to see the query progress. I got this error : {
  "statusCode": 504,
  "error": "Gateway Time-out",
  "message": "Client request timeout"
}  yesterday. I read in online documents, it means my query is running in the background but it is taking time to perform the operation. I am curious to know that how can I solve the time out issue?

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy regarding the mapping I am not sure what mapping you are asking. If it's from the kibana index pattern then here is the mapping. {A :{X : {B:{C}}}

Comment: Post the results of `GET test_index/_mapping`

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy Thank you for your response. I checked it and it is   {{{Y: A :{X : {B:{C}}}

Comment: @PolynomialProton & @ Sathishkumar Rakkiasam it seems that the above query works fine. I checked with different indexes. It was not an immediate response so it took a while to realize. Thank you for your help. Now say if I have 100 index having a similar name pattern for example an index having a name "test_date - MM/DD/YYYY" here the prefix is same "test". Can I write a simple query that delete the field "B" from all these indexes? If so, can you tell me a way. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, your query is correct. Check my answer @MaunilVyas to understand why you get the timeout and how to deal with it.

Comment: Regarding multiple indices, you can use a wildcard. For example: lets say all index have a prefix  `test_date`, you can `POST test_date*/_update_by_query ....` i.e. just replace the index name

Comment: @PolynomialProton Thank you very much. Everything worked for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. You get timeout since its running the process in the background and times out before *completing the task*.

You can [run the query asynchronously](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-task-api) by specifying `wait_for_completion=false`

```
POST test_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed&wait_for_completion=false
{
      "script" : "ctx._source.A.remove('B')", 
       "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "A.B" }
      }
}
```

Above will give a response with taskId

```
{
  "task" : "{taskId:node}"
}
```

Now you can use [task api to get the status of the task](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html#tasks-api-request) using the value from above

```
GET _tasks/{taskId:node}
```

Alternatively, if you dont specify `wait_for_completion=false` and get a time out, you can still get all tasks by actions like below. But, i'd recommend do the first one.

```
GET _tasks?actions=*byquery&detailed.
```

> From comments: Now say if I have 100 index having a similar name
>   pattern for example an index having a name "test_date - MM/DD/YYYY"
>   here the prefix is same "test"

In order to handle multiple indices, you can use the wild card syntax and replace index name with prefix and *

For example, below query will run on all indices that start with `test`:

```
POST test*/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed&wait_for_completion=false
{
      "script" : "ctx._source.A.remove('B')", 
       "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "A.B" }
      }
}
```

Comment: It does remove the field from the index but in the mapping (using GET test_index/_mapping) I can still see the field. Is there a way I can also delete it from the index mapping pattern ?

Comment: One minor correction to your answer. To see the task status the query should not have a bracket. I mean it should be "GET _tasks/taskId:node" not GET _tasks/{taskId:node}.

Comment: Yes. I added the braces to show it’s something that need to be replaced.

Comment: You don’t need to remove the field from the index pattern. It’s like a schema / mapping. So if you want to remove them use mapping api to update new schema.